# Is it bad practice to move an l-value reference parameter?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

I originally assumed that it is bad practice to move an l-value reference parameter. Is this indeed commonly agreed by the C++ developer community?

When I call a function that has an R-value reference parameter, it's clear that I must expect that the passed object can be moved. For a function that has an L-value reference parameter, this is not so obvious (and before move semantics were introduced with C++11, it wasn't possible at all).

However, some other developers I recently talked to don't agree that moving l-value references shall be avoided. Are there strong arguments against it? Or is my opinion wrong?

Since I was asked to provide a code example, here is one (see below). It's an artificial example just for demonstrating the issue. Obviously, after calling modifyCounter2(), a call of getValue() will cause a segmentation fault. However, if I were a user of getValue() without knowing its internal implementation, I would be very surprised. If, on the other hand, the parameter were an R-value reference, I would be totally clear that I should not use the object anymore after calling modifyCounter2().

```
class Counter
{
public:
    Counter() : value(new int32_t(0))
    {
        std::cout << "Counter()" << std::endl;
    }

    Counter(const Counter & other) : value(new int32_t(0))
    {
        std::cout << "Counter(const A &)" << std::endl;

        *value = *other.value;
    }

    Counter(Counter && other)
    {
        std::cout << "Counter(Counter &&)" << std::endl;

        value = other.value;
        other.value = nullptr;
    }

    ~Counter()
    {
        std::cout << "~Counter()" << std::endl;

        if (value)
        {
            delete value;
        }
    }

    Counter & operator=(Counter const & other)
    {
        std::cout << "operator=(const Counter &)" << std::endl;

        *value = *other.value;

        return *this;
    }

    Counter & operator=(Counter && other)
    {
        std::cout << "operator=(Counter &&)" << std::endl;

        value = other.value;
        other.value = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    int32_t getValue()
    {
        return *value;
    }

    void setValue(int32_t newValue)
    {
        *value = newValue;
    }

    void increment()
    {
        (*value)++;
    }

    void decrement()
    {
        (*value)--;
    }

private:
    int32_t* value;      // of course this could be implemented without a pointer, just for demonstration purposes!
};

void modifyCounter1(Counter & counter)
{
    counter.increment();
    counter.increment();
    counter.increment();
    counter.decrement();
}

void modifyCounter2(Counter & counter)
{
    Counter newCounter = std::move(counter);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    auto counter = Counter();

    std::cout << "value: " << counter.getValue() << std::endl;

    modifyCounter1(counter);  // no surprises

    std::cout << "value: " << counter.getValue() << std::endl;

    modifyCounter2(counter);  // surprise, surprise!

    std::cout << "value: " << counter.getValue() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I for one would be very surprised if my object was moved if I passed it by lvalue reference.  Generally one should not violate the principal of least surprise and moving from an lvalue reference does just that.

Comment: An example would help (at least me) to understand your thought process better.

Comment: @NathanOliver In general, I don't see any surprise if the called function modifies the state of an object passed by reference (non `const`).

Comment: Show code which demonstrates this potential bad practice. I'm not 100% sure what is your problem.

Comment: `void foo(const std::string& arg) { bar( std::move(arg) ) }` will call a copy constructor and move a temporary object, this is generally legal but have no sense, because it negate the copy elision.

Comment: Generally, I would not move a non-const l-value reference parameter.  If that was my intent, I'd either have the parameter be pass-by-value (and then move from that value) or r-value reference (which makes the caller use std::move if it is named, or ready-to-use if it is from an unnamed temporary).

Comment: If move constructor leave the moved object in valid state, it might be ok. It is not the case here.

Comment: @Victor: That's clear. I didn't mean const references. My question refers to non-const L-value references.

Comment: @Eljay: Yes, that's exactly what I also thought. But at least some people who answered here seem to have a different opinion.

Comment: @A.Schorr - what is the reason of this move? first call to modifyCounter2 will bring to `~Counter()` and as well as to the `delete value;`

Comment: @VictorGubin No it won't

Comment: Sample was very helpful

Comment: @Jarod42: If I understand you correctly, you think that moving an L-value reference parameter is principally OK, but the implementation of the Counter class is wrong? -- I think the move-constructor itself is ok, but I would have to add a nullptr-check in the other member function (such as getValue) to avoid the crash. But then the questions arises which value should getValue() return? This is just an artifical example, but I think in general it can be sometimes difficult to implement all member function in a sensible way so that they still so non-surprising things after moving.

Comment: @VictorGubin: As I already wrote: this is an artificial example just for explaining my thoughts. Of course, the implementation of modifyCounter2() has no practical sense.

Comment: “C makes it easy to shoot yourself in the foot; C++ makes it harder, but when you do it blows your whole leg off.”
― Bjarne Stroustrup `

Comment: IMO it doesn't matter. if you accept an non const reference then you are telling the caller the value you pass in **can change**. Whether that's because it was moved or assigned makes no difference. You have to know what the likely change is to call the function in the first place.

Comment: If `Counter(Counter && other)` was `value = other.value; other.value = new int;` instead, then `modifyCounter2` is like writing `void Counter::reset()`

Comment: @BiagioFesta The surprise comes from not the modification, but from the fact the object could be put into an unspecified state.  If we did this with a vector for instance, then you can't call `front` on the vector afterwards.

Comment: The bottom line is a non-const parameter can change value. It is the function's responsibility to make sure the new value makes sense to the caller. That *new value* can be the result of a *move* because the caller should not care how the new value is arrived at.

Comment: @NathanOliver There are also things you can not do with a vector that changed value by other means. You can't re-use iterators for example.

Comment: @A.Schorr: moving a l-value might be OK, but implementation of `Counter` is wrong, not really for `getValue` (as state above, `vector::front` cannot be called from empty `vector`), but you no longer can do thing to reenable `counter`, such as `counter = anothercounter`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sure, but even without moving anything the problem remains. The callee may just do `vector.clear()`, even in that case, you cannot use `vector.front()` afterward (just for example). Or just `vector.push_back` will lead all caller iterators into *invalid* state (even worse of moving IMHO)! Of course, my comments here are quite general.

Comment: Maybe I should reformulate my original question: If I move a parameter of a function, are there situations in which it is better to define this parameter as an (non-const) L-value reference parameter instead of an R-value reference or a by-value parameter?

Answer (score 16):

Yes, that is surprising and unconventional.

If you want to permit a move, the convention is to have *pass by value*. You can `std::move` from inside the function as appropriate, while the caller can `std::move` into the argument if they decide they want to forfeit ownership.

This convention is where the notion to name `std::move` that way came from: to promote *explicit* forfeiture of ownership, signifying intent. It's why we put up with the name even though it's misleading (`std::move` doesn't really move anything).

But your way is theft. ;)